# How to handle new events in old consumers topics with kafka and spring

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Having a spring-kafka listener where I listen to (some) events in a topic:

```kotlin
@KafkaListener(id = "my-id", topics = ["my-topic"])
internal class MyListener {

    @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
    fun handleIgnoredEvents(event: Any) {
        // I don't care about these ones
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    fun handle(event: SomethingHappened) {
        // I only care about this one
    }
}
```

While doing a rolling update, a `v2` of this service sends a new type of event (introduced in `v2`) to a `v1` instance. Because of the ignorer function, it will ignored and lost forever.

`v1` and `v2` are in the same consumer group.

I thought about

- Creating a new listener with a new group id in `v2`, but it doesn't seem ideal
- Creating a new topic for it isn't an option.
- Creating a handler in `v2` and starting to publish the new schema in `v3`. But I need to make sure that `v2` has been deployed to prod before `v3`, and not `v1` -> `v3`. And this depends on a release cycle, so no.

Is there any known strategy or best practice for handling this situation?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If the v1 service doesn't know what a `SomethingElseHappended` is, how can it not ignore it (and why shouldn't it)? Surely you have to deploy v2 of the service before you start sending `SomethingElseHappended` events if you must process those events.

Comment: The problem is not that `v1` receives them, but that it ignores them without doing anything (`ack`ing them). Ideally only `v2` instances should receive the new events so that they can do something with them.

Comment: They will be ack'd (get their offsets committed) by the container when `handleIgnoredEvents` exits normally, you don't appear to be using a MANUAL ack mode. Seems like everything will just work like you want; v2 instances will get the new events, v1 instances will ignore them.

Comment: But `v1` and `v2` are part of the same consumer group. Only `v1` gets it. Am I right?

Comment: If they are in the same consumer group, partitions will be distributed across the instances. So partitions assigned to v1 instances will have their new events discarded and partitions assigned to the v2 instances will have their new events processed.

Comment: Interesting, I thought the partitions were the same, but reassigned to the new instances, no matter the version. So why do we need to manage backward compatibility if that's the case? If they only communicate with the same version then there're no compat problems. What am I missing? Or you're saying that both `v1` and `v2` will get the event and `v1` will discard it because of the default handler?

Comment: A single event can only be in one partition; only one member of the group will get an event; the instance that partition is assigned to. If there are multiple events in multiple partitions, some will be ignored, some will be processed. There is no guarantee that a particular partition will always be assigned to a particular instance, unless you are using some kind of custom `PartitionAssignor` (replaced by `ConsumerPartitionAssignor` since `kafka-clients` 2.4).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218721/discussion-between-talabes-and-gary-russell).

Comment: In our case we always pause consumers during a rolling deployment where there is a breaking change - it's worth building in a pause capability for this reason (and generally we find it useful to be able to pause consumers for other reasons)